# URL rewriting not working correctly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I am making a website and I am not getting why `mod_rewrite` is not working.

Here is the present URL: `http://www.treetle.com/profile/index/show/rameshmantha`
and want it to be rewritten to `http://www.treetle.com/profile/rameshmantha`

Where `rameshmantha` is a profile name (which comes dynamically)
and here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-z]+)?$ /profile/index/show/$1[L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1` matches everything. Have you tried swapping the order to:

```
RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-z]+)?$ /profile/index/show/$1[L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```